# Data for the last date not included by the "BETWEEN OPERATOR" IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an oracle query for getting the values between 12pm and 12am ( each day) from dates 11/06/2021 to 16/06/2021. The query i have below will collect the info from the 11th up to the 15th , but will not obtain data for the 16th. Is there any other way i can solve this issue? Thanks a lot for your time

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(datadate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') , 
       ROUND(AVG(BATTERYVOLTAGE),2) AVGVOLTAGE  
FROM   MYTABLE 
WHERE  BATTERYVOLTAGE!= 0  
AND    to_char(datadate, 'hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN '12:00:00' and '24:00:00'  
AND    DATADATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('11/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
                   AND  TO_DATE('16/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datadate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: You mean from 12:00 to 00:00 the next day for each day or for the whole range, i.e. from 2021-06-11 12:00 to 2021-06-12 00:00?

Comment: Hey @stickybit its for each day . Sorry .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wondering how to do it.

Change the formatting of the last date.

```
DATADATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('12/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND  (TO_DATE('22/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')+(1-1/24/60/60))
```

For more info
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=date-queries-using-between

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to subtract 1 second from the next day? `date '2021-06-23' - interval '1' second`

Comment: That's not a good solution. It will fail if the data type used for the column is (changed to) one that allows more precision. Don't use `BETWEEN` use a half open range with `>=` and `<`. And why `22`? The OP's date aren't anywhere that. I assume that's supposed to be `16`.

Comment: Hey @stickybit  i just used 22 as an example. Im using DATE as the datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
datadate BETWEEN to_date('11/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                 AND to_date('16/06/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

includes only rows where `datadate` if before or at 2021-06-16 00:00:00. Everything past 2021-06-16 00:00:00 isn't included.

That's a common mistake. Don't use `BETWEEN` for such things. Use a range with `>=` and `<` instead.

```
    datadate >= to_date('2021-06-11 12:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND datadate < to_date('2021-06-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Hey !! i tried using the >= and <. Still im not getting the value for the last date. i also tried <=

Comment: @jot: And the upper bound really is `datadate < to_date('2021-06-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` -- note **17**, **not** 16?

Answer (score -1):

You will have problems try to query date and time separated; is easier if you join date and time and search for datetime value like to_date('2021-06-11 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') the range you'll get is since 9 at the limit you want